# :first-child not working on <input> within <p>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

((I'm a beginner so this probably has a simple solution, but I've searched with all the keywords I can think of and can't find what I'm looking for. I appreciate any help — clearly I am in over my head.))

I'm trying to give the first radio button within a paragraph a different margin than the rest of the radio buttons. This is what I have:

```css
p.question:first-child input[type=radio] {
       margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<p class="question">
       <input type="radio" name="sample1" /> Yes
       <input type="radio" name="sample1" /> No
       <input type="radio" name="sample1" /> Maybe-So
    </p>
```

Shouldn't this target the first radio button within a paragraph? Please be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting the `first-child` on the `<p>`, not the radio button.

Try this.

```
p.question input[type=radio]:first-child {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5o5h22tq/).

Comment: Thank you for answering this poor simpleton's question. Wish I could accept your answer immediately.

Comment: We all started coding at the beginning. SO is a great resource for finding answers to the questions that we all have.